# Screen resolution not proper in Samsung N100S

Tags: 12.04, resolution

I just got a Samsung n100S notebook and installed ubuntu 12.04. It looks like the resolution of screen is not coming properly. The system is taking 800x600 resolution - whereas I think it should be 1024*768 (not sure though).

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Intel binary Xorg driver for GMA3600 (Cedarview) GPUs!

a). still not full performance but works with 2d acceleration and I could play 720p videos with out problem.

b). Adjust brightness with Fn Keys Work!

How to do?

1. First install generic kernel, reboot and and make sure you're using this kernel:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
   ```
2. Remove pae kernel with their respective headers & reboot at the end of this:

   - `sudo dpkg -l | grep linux-image` (This will show kernels on your system)
   - Remove all package related with pae kernel: `sudo apt-get --remove purge "name of package"`
   - `sudo dpkg -l | grep linux-headers` (This will show headers on your system)
   - Remove all package related with pae headers: `sudo apt-get --remove purge "name of package"`
3. Install the cedarview drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cedarview-drm libva-cedarview-vaapi-driver cedarview-graphics-drivers
   ```
4. Update the Grub Bootloader

   ```
   sudo update-grub2
   ```
5. Reboot the System and joy!

NOTE: can activate 3D acceleration test, to see if it works.
      For this,change Option "AIGLX" to "On" (default settion):

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/intel-cdv/X11/xorg.conf.d/61-cdv-pvr.conf
```