# Unable to install cedarview-drm due to unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, software-installation, acer, aspire

I've been trying to install Intel binary Xorg driver for GMA3600 (Cedarview) GPUs for my Acer Aspire One D270 with Windows 7 Starter, Windows 8, and Ubuntu 12.04.

I've followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/181440/955434) verbatim, but I get the following errors on Step 3 when I try to install the Cedarview drivers:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cedarview-drm:i386 : Depends: grub-gfxpayload-lists:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: linux-headers-generic:i386 (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed or linux-headers-generic-pae:i386 (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: dkms:i386 (>= 2.1.0.0) but it is not installable

cedarview-graphics-drivers:i386 : Depends: xserver-xorg-core:i386 (>= 2:1.10.99.901) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: xorg-video-abi-11:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried and successfully install one of the packages by myself:

```
sudo apt-get install libva-cedarview-vaapi-driver
```

But when I tried to install `cedarview-drm` by myself, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
```

The following information may also help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cedarview-drm:i386 : Depends: grub-gfxpayload-lists:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: linux-headers-generic:i386 (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed or linux-headers-generic-pae:i386 (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: dkms:i386 (>= 2.1.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 64bit installation of Ubuntu(verify with `uname -m`), and the CedarView driver in the repositories is 32bit only.