# Cedarview drivers boot to a blank screen

Tags: drivers, graphics

I'm following the tutorial following tutorial to get my Intel D2700DC motherboard's graphics working: http://daily.siebler.eu/2012/06/ubuntu-12-04-driver-for-intel-cedarview-atom-n2000-und-d2000-serie/

When I boot I'm getting a blank screen. I followed the tutorial and read all the comments. I've also tried:

Install gdm and use this instead of lightdm (ubuntu default)

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Remove previous pae kernel: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/11/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

Reboot before adding cedarview packages.

Have tried with and without the `video=LVDS-1:d` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub`.

I still get a blank screen. I am plugged into a HD screen through the HDMI and have tried the DVI connector also. I can see the grub menu, then a little of the loading and then 'No signal'. I can still ssh into the box though so it is logging in.

```
lspci -v -s 00:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2011
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at 80100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    I/O ports at 20d0 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pvrsrvkm
    Kernel modules: cedarview_gfx


uname -a
Linux test-desktop 3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:45:18 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

The driver is available in the Ubuntu repositories, so no need to add PPAs. You can remove the PPA and the installed packages with

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge ppa:sarvatt/cedarview
```

Then [install the driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172552/screen-resolution-not-proper-in-samsung-n100s).

Hope it works.

Comment: I've tried this and I get the same problem. I made sure I reinstalled the cedarview packages after I removed the ppa as well.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is model related. Can you add the make and model of the notebook to the question.

Comment: It's a desktop motherboard: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-d2700dc.html